# Можно ли успешно заниматься разработкой сайтов, вообще не используя PSD макеты?

Tags: photoshop

Т.е. сразу верстать каркас и постепенно добавлять в него графику. Стиль сайтов - минималистичный или шрифтовый. Активно использовать технологии типа Bootstrap, решения на CSS вместо графики

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем вопросе содержится ответ... При чем тут psd - совсем не понятно... Что хотите, то и используйте. Есть программы - конструкторы сайтов, есть скрипты - конструкторы сайтов. psd удобен, чтобы нарезать графику к примеру. Но это не панацея. Макет можно хоть в illustrator сделать... Какая разница? Заказчик ведь заказывает, а Вы уже для себя выбираете путь наименьшего сопротивления, чтобы было удобно, качественно и быстро.

Comment: да, в принципе Вы правы)

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какая задача. Например для веб-приложений можно начинать с bootstrap'a, там где важнее просто увидеть необходимую информацию (складской учет, учет заявок с сайта и тд). Сайты ориентированные на продажу услуг / товара логичнее начинать с хорошего дизайна.

Answer (score 0):

А кто запрещает-то? Самый верный способ, так это заюзать шаблонизатор.

Comment: Шаблонизатор и макет - не одно и то же. Сам иногда так сайты делаю, начинаю верстать и добавлять графику. Проблема в том, что не зная как будет выглядеть конечный результат, можно потратить много времени на дизайн и верстку.

Comment: Шаблонизатор служит для разграничения дизайнера и разработчика. Разработчик сколотил каркас и пилит со всей душой. Допилил, переквалифицировался в дизайнера и довел до ума дизайн.

Comment: тоже не очень понял причем тут шаблонизатор.... придет заказчик и скажет: хочу в центре страницы яйцо, а вокруг него все меню.
ты сделаешь макет, потом под него сделаешь шаблон... да?

Comment: @thunder так человек написал, что "...заниматься разработкой сайта..." Может он хотел движок под макет сайта точить. Ктож его знает-то?) Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: @lampa ну тут уж смотя с какой стороны смотреть))) но почемуто у меня такой мысли не возникло)

Comment: я разрабатываю сайты на Django и в основном занимаюсь бэк-эндом. Для себя поставил задачу максимально быстро освоить и автоматизировать разработку под фронт-энд, преимущественно без нарезания макетов в Фотошопе

Comment: ну так пишите сайты без картинок, минималистичные. :) вопрос изначально странно изложен же :)